# OpenSSL: Specify packet size of application data

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl

When I do something like this, `apps/openssl s_client -connect 10.102.113.3:443 -ssl3`, client-server communication is created using `openSSL`.

Now, I want to send application data from the client to the server. For example, after doing `apps/openssl s_client -connect 10.30.24.45:443 -ssl3`, I get something like this:

```
...certificate and session details...
---
GET /path/to/file
```

The `GET /path/to/file` all goes in one SSL record. I want to send it in multiple records. 
I assume I have to edit `apps/s_client.c`, and find the place where the `SSL_write` or similar happens.

How do I go about something like that?

Comment: Why? You can't control TCP packetization, and you can't rely on it at the receiving end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out that I needed to change the number of bytes I'm writing using the `SSL_write`.

This is a code snippet, starting at line `1662` of `s_client.c`:

```
if (!ssl_pending && FD_ISSET(SSL_get_fd(con),&writefds))
{
      k=SSL_write(con,&(cbuf[cbuf_off]), (unsigned int)cbuf_len);
      .......
}
```

To make the `application data` be sent in multiple records instead of just the one, change the last parameter in the `SSL_write`.

For example, do this:

```
if (!ssl_pending && FD_ISSET(SSL_get_fd(con),&writefds))
{
      k=SSL_write(con,&(cbuf[cbuf_off]), 1);
      .......
}
```

This will result in something like this:

[image: Notice the multiple records for Application Data instead of just the one]

Notice the multiple records for Application Data instead of just the one.

Answer (score 2):

For a properly designed application the TCP packet sizes and SSL frame sizes should not matter. But there are badly designed applications out there which expect to get like the HTTP request inside a single read, which often means that it must be inside the same SSL frame. If you want to run tests against applications to check for this kind of behavior you either have to patch your `s_client` application or you might use something else, like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
my $sock = IO::Socket::SSL->new('www.example.com:443') or die "$!,$SSL_ERROR";
print $sock "GE";
print $sock "T / HT";
print $sock "TP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
```

This will send the HTTP request header within 3 SSL frames (which might still get put together into the same TCP packet). Since on lots of SSL stacks (like OpenSSL) one SSL_read reads only a single SSL frame this will result in 3 reads necessary to read the full HTTP request.